# WDTException: [0]: One or more columns doesn’t have a header

Tags: plugins, wp-list-table

I am trying to upload an Excel sheet to my WordPress site to create a databases from it but I get the error:

There was an error while trying to save the table! OK WDTException: [0]: One or more columns doesn’t have a header. Please enter headers for all columns in order to proceed.

However, when I check my excel sheet, all headers have filled in names: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PSaUyyMaxp5QWi2P6QDoyHhZw_q3rWo5/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=117419550924909990534&rtpof=true&sd=true (link to my spreadsheet, I see that no column name is empty or NULL)

What edit should I do to my excel sheet o successfully create a database on WordPress?

Thank you!!!!

Below you will see a screenshot of my excel sheet (same as the google drive sheet link) and the error message received from Wordpress).
I do not see anything with the uploaded spread sheet, so I am not sure why I am getting this error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This error is from a plugin, so out of scope here. DId you google it? https://wordpress.org/support/topic/parsererror-wdtexception/

Comment: @vancoder yes i did google it and i arrived to the same article that you linked! however, im still not able to solve my problem since i do not see any column header that is empty or null in my screenshot (the excel sheet that i want to upload is linked in the question , and i do not see anything wrong with the sheet)